# Python : creating a new process

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am new to Python . I was supposed to create a GUI with multiple menus . On clicking a particular menu a new process should start and it should not hang the User Interface . But i am not able to achieve that . After web searches I have made a similar kind of code .

In this code my aim is to make the "print deep"statement active without hanging the UI (which gets active after clicking (Click Me ))

Please help me in this regard .

```
import Tkinter

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter text here.")

        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Click me !",
                                command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,
                              anchor="w",fg="white",bg="blue")
        label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable.set(u"Hello !")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())       
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnButtonClick(self):
        while True:
            print 'deep'
    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You pressed ENTER)" )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're using a `while True` loop - what do you really expect to happen?  Have you tried actually starting a process?

Comment: Actually In real scenario it was supposed to invoke some process which takes 5 mins to complete (Through UI i will be controlling Lab Equipments )so kept infinite while loop

Comment: You need to do more than just use an infinite loop. You need to *wait* on the process to complete, either by polling it in some timer callback, or in another thread.

Comment: The answer import threading

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    # .............................

    def OnButtonClick(self):
       thr = threading.Thread(target=self.print_deep)
       thr.start()

    def print_deep(self):
       while True:
          print 'deep'   is correct , which is given by Pavel. At least it serves my purpose. If there are improvements ,please let me know .

Comment: Okay.. FYI: please don't post code in comments - it's completely unreadable. All you had to say was "Pavel's answer below works for me." And, you don't even have to say anything - just mark his answer as "Accepted".

Answer (score 1):

```
import threading

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    # .............................

    def OnButtonClick(self):
       thr = threading.Thread(target=self.print_deep)
       thr.start()

    def print_deep(self):
       while True:
          print 'deep'
```

If you want to create a new process you need to create separate script that will run in separate process.
I still thing that better solution will be using threads.

proc.py

```
while True:
    print('deep')
```

parent_proc.py

```
import subprocess
import sys    

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    # .............................

    def OnButtonClick(self):
        subprocess.Popen(args=['python', 'proc.py'], stdout=sys.stdout])
```

Comment: threading does NOT start a new process - processes and thread are very very different.

Comment: I know that they are different, but in the context it makes more sense to use threads.

Comment: I will be happier in learning to solve this problem by process . Please help if possible .

Comment: Added an example of using separate process to the answer.

Comment: Now error is coming :  Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/deekumar/Desktop/let us c codes/PYTHON/24-12-2014/parent_proc.py", line 40, in OnButtonClick
    subprocess.Popen(args=['python', 'proc.py'], stdout=[sys.stdout])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 702, in __init__
    errread, errwrite), to_close = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)

Comment: Is it the full error message? You posted the stack trace, but usually there is an exception type and some info regarding the error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple threads to start an external process. `Popen()` doesn't wait for the child process to end. It returns immediately. Here's a [complete code example that starts/stops a tkinter progressbar on the start/end of a subprocess without using threads](https://gist.github.com/zed/4067619#file-progressbar-nothreads-py)
.

---

Unrelated: to run `while True: print 'deep'; time.sleep(1)` without blocking the GUI (assuming `print('deep')` does not block for long), you could use `parent.after()` method:

```
def OnButtonClick(self):
    self._step()    

def _step(self):
    print('deep')
    self.parent.after(1000, self._step) # call _step in a second
```