# Disabling a button's functionality

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, semaphore

I am a beginner in python . I had problem in threading which got resolved day before yesterday at stackoverflow.com . Link to that problem is as follows :   [Python : creating a new process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633942/python-creating-a-new-process/27640043#27640043)

Now i am stuck with another problem . In the code attached below i want to disable the function of Button OnButtonClick2 for the time my OnButtonClick1 is doing something .

```
import Tkinter
import threading
import time
class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter text here.")



        button1 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Exp1 ",
                                command=self.OnButtonClick1)
        button1.grid(column=1,row=0)


        button2 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Exp2 ",
                                command=self.OnButtonClick2)
        button2.grid(column=1,row=1)


        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())       
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnButtonClick1(self):
        thr = threading.Thread(target=self.print_deep1)
        thr.start()
    def print_deep1(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        print 'deep'


    def OnButtonClick2(self):
        thr = threading.Thread(target=self.print_deep2)
        thr.start()
    def print_deep2(self):
       while True:
          print 'deepak'


    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You pressed ENTER)" )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: If my problem statement looks unclear please tell me . I can elaborate that as well .

Comment: My question is when i click Exp1 button and Exp2 in succession then Exp2 should not perform its work (since Exp1 is still doing sth ). How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest (not the best) is to point onclick2 to dumb function; but you must know when threads on button1 finish job. Rename OnButtontClick2 - onBtClick2 and `self.OnButtonClick2 = lambda *arg:None`. When thread finish job `self.OnButtonClick2 = self.onBtClick2`.

Oh, and stop naming your method's like classes. Start with lower letter or snake_style, is more easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Is following code may be one of the approach to solve the problem :

```
import Tkinter
import threading
import time

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    global sempahore

    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()
        self.kick=True

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter text here.")



        button1 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Exp1 ",
                                command=self.OnButtonClick1)
        button1.grid(column=1,row=0)


        button2 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Exp2 ",
                                command=self.OnButtonClick2)
        button2.grid(column=1,row=1)


        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())       
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnButtonClick1(self):
        if (self.kick == True):
            print 'before assignment self.kick =  %s' %(self.kick,)
            self.kick=False
            print 'after assignment self.kick =  %s' %(self.kick,)
            thr = threading.Thread(target=self.print_deep1)
            thr.start()        
    def print_deep1(self):
        print 'on entering function self.kick =  %s' %(self.kick,)
        print (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        time.sleep(10)
        print (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        print 'deep'
        self.kick= True
        print 'at end of function self.kick =  %s' %(self.kick,)


    def OnButtonClick2(self):
        if (self.kick !=False):
            thr = threading.Thread(target=self.print_deep2)
            thr.start()
    def print_deep2(self):
        print self.kick
        print (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        time.sleep(5)
        print (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        print 'deep1'
        self.kick= True

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You pressed ENTER)" )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```